# node js project structure, where to put classes

Tags: node.js, oop, ecmascript-6

So i have a few Classes written in node with es6 and i wounder where would be the right place to put them in a nodejs project

are those `modules`? because those are already used for other types of code bits.

defiantly not `models` those are saved for the database.

Right now i'm thinking of warping them into a standalone node module. i looked around but couldn't find any examples of this use case.

Here is the structure i currently have (express app):

```
/models
    - Holds all the database model definitions
/modules
    - holds one time bits of code, authentication, autherization, email services etc.
/public - client side stuff
    /css
    /js
    /lib - 3rd party front end
/routes - express route defenitions
/views - routes template files
app.js
config.js
package.json
```

No i have a game running in one of the routes, where should i put that game logic? (i.e classes)

Comment: you can put them in /helpers

Comment: @FastTurtle i can, but are those really "helpers" it's more of the core if you as me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an application structured by following,creating a app folder,put all the class files in it and only putting one class in each js file.

```
//------ MyClass01.js ------
export default class { ··· } 

//------ MyClass02.js ------
export default class { ··· }
```

And import all class into the main.js file.

```
//------ Main.js ------
import MyClass1 from 'MyClass01';
import MyClass2 from 'MyClass02';
const inst01 = new MyClass1();
const inst02 = new MyClass2();
```

Just for your reference,it might not be the best practice.

Comment: I understand you use babel? anyways i like your approach i might just go with it

Comment: Yes,or if your project is in harmony mode you don't need it.